# Session data not being written

Tags: php, database, session, pdo

When using the login system on my site, everything runs smoothly but the session data for the username and userid is not being written.

Here is my code...I took out the validation part because it had nothing to do with the session data not being written.

```
<?php

/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

if {

validation here
}
else
{
/*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

/*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
$password = sha1( $password );

/*** connect to database ***/
include("config.php");

try
  {

    /*** prepare the select statement ***/
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT userID, username, password FROM users 
                WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

    /*** bind the parameters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** check for a result ***/
    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $dbusername = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);

    /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
    if($user_id == false)
    {
            $message = 'Login Failed';
    }
    /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
    else
    {
            /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            session_write_close();
            header("Location: index.php");
    }


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
    $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later"';
}
}
?>
```

Here is my page where I am calling the session data. I only took out the part where I am calling the session data, and it's the only place where I have session_start()

```
<?php session_start();
print_r($_SESSION, TRUE); ?>
```

Comment: Get rid of session_write_close() for sh*ts and grins and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: var_dump $user_id and $dbusername please.

Comment: show the page where you are calling the session values.

Comment: replace the '$message = 'We are ...' with: echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();

Answer (score 0):

We can view the session data in those pages where there is session_start();
I think you are printing the session data in index.php, So in index.php there must be 
session_start(); before printing the output.

Comment: I do have session_start() on index.php.